# Comparing LSF cluster bjobs output

Tags: bash

I am using and LSF computing cluster and trying to include in my code, a loop to check when the queue is empty using `bjobs -p` using the following code:

```
s1=$(bjobs -p)
s2="No pending job found"

if [ "$s1" == "$s2" ]; then
    echo "TRUE"
fi
```

This just prints the output of `bjobs -p` which is equal to `No pending job found` rather than echoing `TRUE`

Comment: `bjobs -sum` will put much less load on LSF than `bjobs -p`.  Your LSF admin will thank you.  `bjobs -p` will return details for each pending job.  `bjobs -sum` just returns a counter of pending, running, etc jobs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to redirect [stderr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_.28stderr.29) to stdout:

```
s1="$(bjobs -p 2>&1)"
```

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a number of things that could be wrong here. First, it's wise with this kind of is statement to also give it an else where it echos "FALSE" if the statement is not true, this ensures you're not just having an if issue, like this:

```
if [ "$s1" == "$s2" ]; then
    echo "TRUE"
else
    echo "FALSE"
fi
```

You should also have the script echo what the contents of s1 are. There's a chance that the strings are just different.

They could also be more subtly different, with a hidden character or sneaky carriage return. You can check this by running your script and piping it with cat -A like so:

```
./script.sh | cat -A
```

this will show you if the string stored in $s1 is actually the same. This would work best if you echo both $s1 and $s2 one after the other for comparison.

This hidden character could be causing your if to evaluate them as different.